# The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

Hi All i am trying to connect mongodb with php  codeigniter framework.

i have made changes in
**php.in file   extension=php_mongodb.dll**

and put file in xampp/php/ext/php_mongodb.dll

when i  load my php dashboard  i found there mongodb is install  and get this message.
[image]

but still i am facing issue there  **The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled**

i have placed  Mongo_db.php in library folder and also mongo_db.php  in config folder.

How can i solve my problem.

i am using php 7 n xampp and mongo db install  in my machine 3.4 version

Comment: Apache (XAMPP) restarted?

Answer (score 1):

While working with PHP7 and codeigniter and mongo, you do not need to have the mongo_db library and config files in those respective folders.. You can remove them.

1. Get a composer generated autoload file (http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php)
2. In your php.ini file, write

   ```
   extension=mongodb.so
   ```
3. Use the new syntax for connecting to Mongodb -

   ```
   $client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
   ```
4. In your php file, load the autoload file

   ```
   require('/home/ubuntu/vendor/autoload.php');
   ```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I installed mongoDB from composer then I wanted to start working with CodeIgniter/mongoDB. put the autoload.php in the constructor, make sure you get the correct address to autoload.php.

Comment: @Chad - Can you please post your answer with details like CI, PHP and MongoDB versions

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that CodeIgniter does not work yet with the new "mongodb" extension that you have installed, but instead relies on the old "mongo" extension.

You can still find the latter online (http://pecl.php.net/mongo), but you should probably find a few to get CodeIgniter to use the new one that you have installed instead.